# CSS translate() property not working on :active selector

Tags: css

So I have this cool little radial menu that pops out of nowhere when you click a FAB. It took a lot of animations and trial and error, especially since I am a noob, but eventually it worked as I wanted it to. However I recently realised that the transform(3px, 3px) that I added to one of my :active properties does not work. This is quite puzzling to me, as the exact same animation was added to the FAB and it works fine there. You can see the whole thing in action here: (https://codepen.io/BGGrieco/pen/EmzRLw?editors=0100), I commented out the shadow animation, which works, to bring attention to the fact that the translate(3px, 3px) does not happen.
Relevant code of what works and what doesn't:

```
#fab
{
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #6eadea;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 6px 10px 18px #686868;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#fab:active
{
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 12px #585858;
}
```

^ works fine ^

```
#top
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 34.5%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 6px 16px 24px #999999;
}

#top:active
{
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  /*box-shadow: 6px 10px 18px #686868; COMMENTED THIS OUT TO FOCUS ON PROBLEM*/
}
```

^ Nada, nej, niet, zilch ^

I pray to the internet gods that I am not making a fool of myself (again) by totally forgetting a comma or a semicolon somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform:translate isn't working on the element because the element has another, inline transform style set on it, and inline styles (usually) take precedence over styles defined in CSS. Take a look at the Chrome Inspector:

[image]

It looks like you are setting this in Javascript. Rememeber, all transform properties act as one, so if you need multiple transforms like both scale and translate it becomes:

```
transform: translate(3px, 3px) scale(0, 0);
```

You won't be able to override the transform property with your current Javascript, I would recommend also putting the scale in CSS.

Comment: This always gets me. I wish the transform properties had their own individual properties, like `scale: 0, 0;`

Comment: you can now do this by using seperate css variables and setting them in js like `element.style.setProperty('--scale', scaleAmount);`

Answer (score 1):

hye brian, sadly I have no idea why this doesn't work as intended, a solution might be using `margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 3px;`? it works in your codepen. I don't know if this suffices for you, let me know if you want me to dig deeper ;p

Comment: Thank you @Sam Apostel. It is a good fix, but I will wait to see if someone can understand what's going on before accepting it as the answer. Meantime I will use your solution, good thinking!